# SQL Query - Find Value and Get Data From Other Tables Around Same Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am green when it comes to SQL queries. Very green.

I have 3 tables. First dbo.StringTable maintains a table of variables that have strings as their data.

```
DateAndTime               TagIndex     Val  
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   42           on load      
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   43           on load      
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   44           START        
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   45           on load      
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   46           on load
```

Similarly, dbo.FloatTable has the tags that have floats as their values;

```
DateAndTime               TagIndex     Val  
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   47           33.4     
2018-10-28 11:48:12.000   48           42.3     
2018-10-28 11:48:17.000   47           16.3
2018-10-28 11:48:17.000   48           18.0     
2018-10-28 11:48:22.000   47           52.1
```

The third (dbo.TabTable) has the static mapping between TagIndex and TagName

```
TagName                   TagIndex  
gtg_evnt\4                45    
gtg_evnt\5                46    
plc\system\capacity\1     47    
plc\system\load\1         48    
plc\system\req_load\1     49
```

Data is logged to both FloatTable and StringTable every 5 seconds, but when an 'event' happens, it triggers extra data to be written to both.

What I need to do is;

1. Search StringTable for an 'event', by looking for a Val of START or
   STOP.
2. Once found, use the DateAndTime to retrieve data from
   FloatTable AND StringTable (inclusive of the 'event' found above) of 10 seconds before and 10 seconds after the event.
3. Use TagTable to change the TagIndex with the proper name.

This kind of query is out of my league. I have spent 3 hours reading up on SQL commands, and have made some progress, but this could take me hours/days when I'm pretty sure one of you guys would solve this in minutes...

Based on the answer below, I have done the following. And after spacing it out like this, I worked through what each part does - makes a lot more sense.

I have updated it based on my final query, and added some comments in the hopes it helps someone.

```
SELECT
    B.DateandTime 
   ,D.TagName
   ,B.Val

/** First, make a derived table 'A' with all the GTG Events in the past 1 day **/
FROM
  ( SELECT DateAndTime
          ,TagIndex
          ,Val 
    FROM [FTViewDatalog].[dbo].StringTable
    WHERE val in ('Start','Stop') AND
           DateAndTime >= GETDATE()-1
    ) A

/** The UNION creates a big table with StringTable and FloatTable merged together **/
/** The INNER JOIN then takes each of the DateAndTime from A, and gets the events from 10 seconds before and 10 seconds after **/
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT DateAndTime
          ,TagIndex
          ,Val 
    FROM [FTViewDatalog].[dbo].StringTable
    UNION
    SELECT DateAndTime
          ,TagIndex
          ,Cast(Val AS varchar(50)) AS Val 
    FROM [FTViewDatalog].[dbo].FloatTable
    ) B
    ON B.DateAndTime BETWEEN DATEADD(ss,-10,A.DateAndTime ) AND  DATEADD(ss,10,A.DateAndTime )

/** Use an INNER JOIN to 'convert' the TagIndex into a TagName **/
INNER JOIN [FTViewDatalog].[dbo].TagTable D ON D.TagIndex=B.TagIndex

/** Use this if you want to filter out specific tags **/
/** WHERE D.TagName IN ('plc\system\req_load\1','plc\system\load\1', 'plc\system\capacity\1') OR D.TagName LIKE 'gtg_evnt\[1-7]' **/

/** Sort by date **/
ORDER BY B.DateAndTime ASC
```

Comment: Can you give an example from the data defined here?

Comment: What is the "proper name"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The final table should show DateAndTime, TagName and Vale (so replace TagIndex with TagName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would assist you feel free to let me know any concern,

```
Select C.TagName as OriginalEventName,A.DateandTime as OriginalEventTimeStamp,D.TagName as ParallelEventName,B.DateandTime as ParallelEventTimeStamp
from
(Select Cast(DateAndTime as datetime) as DateAndTime,Tagindex,cast(Val as Varchar(50)) as Val from StringTable
where val in ('Start','Stop'))A
inner join Tabtable C on C.Tagindex=A.TagIndex
Inner join
(Select Cast(DateAndTime as datetime) as DateAndTime,Tagindex,cast(Val as Varchar(50)) as Val from StringTable
Union
Select cast(DateAndTime as datetime) as DateAndTime,Tagindex,cast(Val as Varchar(50)) as Val FloatTable)B
on B.DateAndTime between DATEADD(ss,-10,A.DateAndTime ) and DATEADD(ss,10,A.DateAndTime )
inner join Tabtable D on D.Tagindex=B.TagIndex
```

Comment: I think 
**Union Select cast(DateAndTime as datetime) as DateAndTime,Tagindex,cast(Val as nvarchar(50)) as Val from FloatTable where val in ('Start','Stop')** this portion will not work because FloatTable doesn't have Val like 'START' or 'STOP'

Comment: Yup. Literally no idea what you have written... :/

Comment: I’m getting the values from string table and float table together and the purpose is to get get all datetime in one place so for the considered START and STOP from the String table we can get all the datetime rows within the +10 sec to -10sec interval, that union of flot table in the sub query A is redundant so will remove it there.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran I have taken your code and fixed some typos and spaced it out so it was easier for me to read. It works well! I might even understand it slightly... I just need to filter the final list (there are hundreds of TagIndex/TagName within that +-10s period, and I only need to see 3 of them)

Comment: You can do that by partitioning. I dont have my laptop with me right now will help you with that in a while

Comment: I just added `where D.TagName in ('tagname1','tagname2')` after the last line you had (`inner join`)

Comment: Does it solve your issue are you getting only the required output ?

Comment: In your case the out put will only consist tag name 1 and tag name 2 if it’s what you require then totally fine, have a nice day mate cheers :)

Comment: It was a good question I had some good time while thinking a solution for it thumbs up for that

Comment: Yeah - great work! The only thing I can think of to make it better (if it's even possible or worth it), is to perform the `where` filter earlier - maybe in the `Select from FloatTable`. At the moment, it has to do the `On` on ALL the data, then `Inner Join` on ALL the data, and then I finally do my filter.

Comment: Yes within the sub query B you can filter it out that way it would be optimized as you say